# Converting Mathematica to Python - arccos and sqrt

Tags: python, numpy, wolfram-mathematica, sqrt

I am attempting to convert the following Mathematica expression into Python. Somehow, Mathematica can easily deal with negative in the square root, and the argument of arcsec being outside of the domain.

Can someone help me make a Python expression that works? Or at least tell me how Mathematica (which I'm less familiar with) handles these issues?

Mathematica expression (to plot over 0.1-100)

```
LogLogPlot[(p0 rs^2 (Sqrt[(R - rs) (R + rs)] (-2 R rs + \[Pi] (R - rs) (R + rs))
- 2 (R^3 - 2 R rs^2) ArcSec[R/rs]))/(R ((R - rs) (R + rs))^(3/2)) /. {rs -> 1, p0 -> 10},
{R, 0.1, 100}]
```

Python expression

```
rho0 * rs ** 2 * (np.pi * (R-rs)*(R+rs) - 2 *R *rs) /(R *(R-rs) *(R+rs)) - rho0 * rs **2
 * (2 *np.arccos(rs/R))*(R **3 - 2 *R *rs) / (R *((R-rs) *(R+rs)) **(3/2))
```

When R < rs (which is of course the region I am interested in), I get undefined values for arccos, and nonsense values for the square root.

Any and all tips would be helpful!

Comment: You can use the [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/cmath.html) module to work with complex numbers in Python.

Comment: for arg greater than one arccos is purely imaginary. , `arccos(x) = (1/i) log(x + sqrt(x2-1))`  (I think, suggest you verify). With that and your sqrt also being imaginary you can write your formula to give always real result.

Answer (score 0):

here is the mathematica formulation that does not use complex numbers.

```
f[R_, rs_, p0_] := 
   Which[R >= rs,
           (p0 rs^2 (Sqrt[(R - rs) (R +rs)]
           (-2 R rs + Pi (R - rs) (R + rs)) - 
           2 (R^3 - 2 R rs^2) ArcSec[R/rs]))/
           R ((R - rs) (R + rs))^(3/2)),
         R < rs,
           (p0 rs^2 ( Sqrt[(rs - R ) (R + rs)]
           (-2 R rs + Pi (R - rs) (R + rs)) - 
           2 (R^3 - 2 R rs^2) Log[rs/R + Sqrt[(rs/R)^2 - 1]]))/
           (-R ((rs - R) (R + rs))^(3/2) )]

  LogLogPlot[f[R, 1, 10], {R, 0.1, 100}]
```

[image]

aside, both expressions blow up for `R==rs` exactly, however the limit exists:

```
Limit[(p0 rs^2 (Sqrt[(R - rs) (R +  rs)] (-2 R rs + \[Pi] (R - rs) (R + rs)) 
  2 (R^3 - 2 R rs^2)   ArcSec[R/rs]))/  (R ((R - rs) (R + rs))^(3/2)) , 
   R -> rs,  Assumptions -> {p0 > 0, R > 0, rs > 0}]
```

> p0 (-8 + 3 Pi) rs /3

```
%/. {rs->1,p0->10}
```

> 4.74926

you can add that case to the conditional if needed.